# Debug with internal command window Python Tools and Vistual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

I just installed Python Tools with Visual Studio 2013 (Shell) and whenever I run a debug of the program, a separate window pops up for the interpreter:

[image]

I can however run the program using the internal interactive console:

[image]

However this doesn't seem to stop at any breakpoints that I set in the code.  Is there a way to force the system to use the internal console for debugging instead of using a separate windowed console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the shell by changing Environment options in Python Tools with Visual Studio, change the default path to point pythonw.exe.

Here is the steps:

1. TOOLS -> Python tools -> Python Environment
2. Open Environment options, Add Environment, Enter whatever you want to name it.
3. Copy all the options in the default Environment except change "Path:" to path of **pythonw.exe**. Hit OK and made the new Environment as the default environment.

[image: Python Environment]

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to hide the console window entirely, but all output from it should be tee'd to Output window, so you can use that if you don't like the console.

There's also a Debug Interactive window (Debug -> Windows -> Python Debug Interactive) that you may find of help, if what you want specifically is being able to stop at breakpoints and then work with variables etc in a REPL environment. Once enabled, this window will provide you a live REPL of the debugged process, and when you're stopped anywhere, you can interact with it. Like Output window, it does not suppress the regular console window, but it mirrors its output.

Answer (score 2):

Although this seems old, solution pasted elsewhere can help someone searching an answer.

I cannot comment since I don't have rep.

Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486749/4809808

> As far as the console window it will generally open unless you mark your app as a Windows application in project properties (this will launch pythonw.exe which doesn't include a console window).
>
> If you right click on your project and choose Properties in the "General" tab there's a "Windows Application" checkbox below Working Directory.